# Tag Merge Discussion: languages, programming-languages

Tags: discussion, tags

[programming-languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages) --> [languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages)

After thinking about it, and Jeff's post, there should be few questions about spoken or written languages (most, if not all, would be off-topic for too localized) here. As such, it seems like languages is the best tag for the site.

Answer (score 2):

Agree, most people use them synonymously anyway. And there seems slight confusion. In a context with internationalization the usage as natural language would make sense, like in [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95202/if-someone-was-making-software-able-to-display-content-in-any-written-language) question. But they could (and most likely should) use [internationalization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalization). In addition there is [natural-language](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language) and [spoken-languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-languages). Maybe some text in the tag wiki would help users to make the distinction.

btw: We have both: [language](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) and plural [languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages). Could be merged as well I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think on a site titled "programmers" we necessarily should disambiguate [language](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language).

All tags *start* with the assumption that they are most relevant to the audience *of that site*.

I think [languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages) (the plural form) is generally better but I strongly feel that adding "programming-" to tags is highly redundant on a site by, and for, programmers...

Comment: My original thought was perhaps there would be question about some kind of documentation, but now that I think about it, any questions would be applicable of what language the document is written it. Anything else would be too localized or perhaps appropriate for one of the language Stack Exchanges. Maybe programming-languages -> languages would be best.